# identify helpcontextid in visual studio 2010 for windows application form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, chm, helpcontext

I am new to visual studio 2010 and c#.I am trying to locate helpcontextid in properties panel but i couldn't find it out.I have many questions as follows

- Is helpcontextid a property for windows application
- If yes where can I find the solution?If no what should I do to add helpcontextid?
- Can helpcontextid added for all the events or do we have some limitations?

Answer (score 1):

Context-sensitive help sometimes seems to be a bit difficult sometimes. You need to create a CHM including **help context ID's** or you may want to use help topics on a server.

The Windows Forms supports a "What's this .." HelpButton and / or <kbd>F1</kbd> - Help on individual controls based on Help files. To attach Help topics within a Help file (that is either HTML or HTMLHelp 1.x/Help 2.x format) to specific controls on Windows Forms you need to use the HelpProvider component. The HelpProvider component will associates an HTMLHelp 1.x Help file (CHM) or a single HTML file with your Windows Form application.

To provide this Help in your application, you have to use the HelpProvider control which you can find in the Toolbox on the Windows Forms tab. Drag and Drop a HelpProvider component from the Toolbox to your form. It is a component rather than a control, so when you put it on your form it will sit in the component tray below. Rename this component to "hlpHtmlLocal". This component gives every control on the form three new properties called HelpKeyword, HelpNavigator and HelpString on hlpProvider1.

For further information see [Help for controls with VB .NET](http://www.help-info.de/en/Visual_Basic_net/vbnet_htmlhelp.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and your suggestion helped me